# Python connect to MySQL failed with error "dh key too small"

Tags: python, mysql, ssl

I'm trying to connect to the company's MySQL database. The policy was that I am to connect *only* using SSL.

I am provided the `username`, `CA certificate`, `certificate`, and `private key`.

If I use [**HeidiSQL**](http://www.heidisql.com), I can connect without problem.

However, I cannot connect using **Python 2.7.11** with the `mysql-connector-python-rf` (v2.1.3).

Here's my simple connection tester program:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division, unicode_literals

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.constants import ClientFlag

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='myusername',
    host='myserver.example.com',
    port=3306,
    client_flags=[ClientFlag.SSL],
    ssl_ca='/path/to/ca.crt',
    ssl_cert='/path/to/user.crt',
    ssl_key='/path/to/user.key'
)

cnx.close()
```

I *always* end up with this exception:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at
'myserver.example.com:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: SSL_NEGATIVE_LENGTH] dh key too small
(_ssl.c:590)
```

I've tried searching for answers, but there doesn't seem to be a solution except changing the settings on the *server side*, which is simply a no-no.

How can I fix and/or work around this issue?

---

**Update for More Info:** I'm creating my program on Windows 10, using **PyCharm 5.0.3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of desperation, I installed the module **`MySQL-python`** and replaced the connection method as follows:

```
import MySQLdb

ssl = {
    'cert': '/path/to/user.crt',
    'key': '/path/to/user.key'
}

cnx = MySQLdb.connect(
    host='myserver.example.com', port=3306, user='myusername',
    ssl=ssl
)
```

... lo and behold! I have no problems with DH whatsoever!! It works!!!

So one alternative solution if someone happens upon this problem, is to change the module used to connect.

Answer (score 4):

As of this writing, with mysql-connector-python 2.1.4 pure python module from Oracle (the one you are using is a fork of version 2.1.3) supports the undocumented connection configuration kwarg `ssl_cipher` in your connection string (since it basically passes it to python's `ssl` module). So strip all Diffie-Hellman ciphers from the cipher list and you may be able to work around this problem, depending on whether your mysql server supports non-Diffie-Hellman ciphers. The following works on official Python 2.7.12 amd64 win32 against MySQL 5.6.17-65.0-rel65.0-log . **Note:** This only works when dealing with the *pure python* version of the module!. If you use the compiled C extension module, it may not accept ssl_cipher, YMMV.

```
import mysql.connector
import getpass

dsn = {
    'database': 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA',
    'host': 'mysqlserver',
    'port': '3306',
    'ssl_ca': '', 
    # ^^^ this sets cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_NONE
    # in mysql/connector/network.py:415
    # so no server cert verification is attempted

    'use_pure': True 
    # setting ssl_cipher may only work with the pure python driver
    # but this is the default anyway
}

dsn['user'] = raw_input('Enter Username: ')
dsn['password'] = getpass.getpass('Enter password: ')

try:
    dbconn = mysql.connector.connect(**dsn)
    # this will raise the 'Weak DH key' exception
except mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError as e:
    print e

dsn['ssl_cipher'] = 'HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'

# this is a standard openssl ciphersuite string
# where !DH and !aNULL means don't use any DH ciphers or null ciphers
# this option is officially undocumented

try:
    dbconn = mysql.connector.connect(**dsn)
except mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError:
    raise
else:
    assert isinstance(dbconn, mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection)
```

### How the sausage is made

In mysql-connector-python 2.1.4, the following lines in the module's source show how this works:
`mysql/connector/abstracts.py: Lines 298 - 313:`

```
for key, value in config.items():
    try:
       DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION[key]
    except KeyError:
        raise AttributeError("Unsupported argument '{0}'".format(key))
    # SSL Configuration
    if key.startswith('ssl_'):
        set_ssl_flag = True
        self._ssl.update({key.replace('ssl_', ''): value})
    else:
        attribute = '_' + key
        try:
            setattr(self, attribute, value.strip())
        except AttributeError:
            setattr(self, attribute, value)
```

Then in `mysql/connector/connection.py lines 130-134`:

```
if client_flags & ClientFlag.SSL and ssl_options:
    packet = self._protocol.make_auth_ssl(charset=charset,
                                          client_flags=client_flags)
    self._socket.send(packet)
    self._socket.switch_to_ssl(**ssl_options)
```

`_socket.switch_to_ssl()` is found in `mysql/connector/network.py lines 406-421`:

```
def switch_to_ssl(self, ca, cert, key, verify_cert=False, cipher=None):
    """Switch the socket to use SSL"""
    if not self.sock:
        raise errors.InterfaceError(errno=2048)

    try:
        if verify_cert:
            cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
        else:
            cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_NONE

        self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(
            self.sock, keyfile=key, certfile=cert, ca_certs=ca,
            cert_reqs=cert_reqs, do_handshake_on_connect=False,
            ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, ciphers=cipher)
        self.sock.do_handshake()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a security issue and the server side is affected by a [weak DH key](https://weakdh.org/).  Current versions of OpenSSL enforce a minimal length of the DH key to protect against attacks using weak DH keys.

If your company is really interested in security and not just believe that magically sprinkling some (insecure) SSL around will do it, then they should fix the problem on the server side. To work around the problem on the client side your Python would need to be linked against an older version of OpenSSL which does not yet enforce a minimal DH key length.

Comment: Ah, I see. So it was because Python's OpenSSL on my side was more secure than the OpenSSL on the server side. Just a question: If we upgrade the OpenSSL on the server side, do the certs and keys need to be replaced?

Comment: @pepoluan: no, you can keep the existing certs and keys.

Comment: Is there another way to override this behavior on the client? (by setting an environment variable that overrides this in openssl?) (I'm asking about official python windows distributions). I'm seeing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015537/python-requests-exceptions-sslerror-dh-key-too-small for urllib, I wonder if there is a similar hack to support it in the official mysql python connector

Comment: I guess one option is to locally fork the mysql python connector and modify the module to select a non-DH cipherset.

Comment: @cowbert: given the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) I don't see a way to limit the ciphers on the client.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I took a look at the source for mysql-connector-python 2.1.4 from oracle, and based on mysql/connector/abstracts.py line 307 and mysql/connector/connection.py line 134 and mysql/connector/network.py lines 406-420 you can indeed pass ssl_cipher into the connection string. Tested ok to me if I set ssl_cipher to 'HIGH:!DH:!aNULL'

Comment: @cowbert: nice find of this undocumented function (or did I miss the documentation?). It would be nice if you could create an answer for this.

Comment: it's undocumented I had to trawl the source