# Urllib3 error "SSL: wrong signature type"

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, urllib3

When I run the following code in python 3.8.5 from an Ubuntu Server:

```
import urllib3
import certifi
url = "https://www.website.com"
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())
content = http.request("GET", url, preload_content=False).read()
```

The following error occurr:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 996, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 366, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE] wrong signature type (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyFile.py", line 46, in <module>
    content = urllib3.PoolManager().request("GET", url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 75, in request
    return self.request_encode_url(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 97, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 330, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 747, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 747, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 747, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.website.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /path/to/web/page.html (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE] wrong signature type (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

The system is updated as all the libraries I am using

Running the same code on my Windows 10 pc results in no errors

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer by myself referencing this GitHub issue: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4775

I solved the problem using the code below:

```
import urllib3
url = "https://www.website.com"

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.set_ciphers('DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1')
http = urllib3.PoolManager(
   ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS,
   ssl_context=ctx)
content = http.request("GET", url, preload_content=False).read()
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also keep using requests with the following code (inspired from your answer and the [requests documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version)) :

```
import ssl
import requests
import urllib3

class SslOldHttpAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        ctx.set_ciphers('DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1')

        self.poolmanager = urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager(
            ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS,
            ssl_context=ctx)

url = "https://www.website.com"
s = requests.Session()
s.mount(url, SslOldHttpAdapter())
r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore for some websites, using OPENSSL 1.1.1n in Python 3.10. Example: billboard-japan.com/d_news/detail/119991

Answer (score 1):

try to disable the system proxy

```
proxies = {"http": None, "https": None}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer about creating a new context with SECLEVEL=1 does not work for me in Python 3.11.1 on Windows (with `OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022`).

But this (inspaired by [Python - requests.exceptions.SSLError - dh key too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015537/python-requests-exceptions-sslerror-dh-key-too-small)) works:

```
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1'
r = requests.get('https://www.billboard-japan.com')
print(r.status_code)
```