# SSL connection error when to use httpx lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, httpx

I using [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org) and request some old website's xhr

```
# ... some errors
httpx.ConnectError: [SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:1131)
```

I was resolve this issue when to use `requests`  [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015537/python-requests-exceptions-sslerror-dh-key-too-small)

How can I solve this problem in httpx?

- `verify=False` is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you put this code at the top it is solved

```
httpx._config.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ":ALL:@SECLEVEL=1"
```

But I'm not sure if it's the right way