# SSL CertVerification error in Jupyter noteboook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am getting SSL Cert Verification error while running python code in jupyter notebook. This is happening on in few systems but working fine in my system. Can anyone please help with this.

I tried reinstalling jupyter notbook mulitple times and used different network but still issue is same.

Comment: Shaik - How did you solve this? I am having the same problem:---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\httpcore\_exceptions.py:10, in map_exceptions(map)
      9 try:
---> 10     yield
     11 except Exception as exc:  # noqa: PIE786

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python3

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your installation, but it could also be a problem with the remote system if it's doing something like:

- Using a self-signed certificate.
- Using a corporate certificate that's trusted by your OS but not part of the [`certifi`](https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi) package.
- Using a [cipher that's too weak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015537/python-requests-exceptions-sslerror-dh-key-too-small) in newer versions of Python.
- Using a certificate that's otherwise fine but doesn't match the site being accessed.

If you could include the precise code being used and error being returned, that would help narrow down the problem.