# Python - requests.exceptions.SSLError - dh key too small (new version)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, rsa

I'm attempting to scrape some internal pages using Python and requests. I've provided proper site certin the script, but still getting the following error:

`urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:1002)`

I found this question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015537/python-requests-exceptions-sslerror-dh-key-too-small/76217135#76217135) for the exact same issue, but none of the solutions work with the newest versions of everything.

I have tried creating a script for the API on the site, but same error. Also tried providing public key/private key, but I think that's going on the wrong path, I just don't have much experience in Python.